# Azure Dev Ops CICD copy publish not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-functions

I have the following YAML in my build pipeline.

```
  #Step 3, Copy Files
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        #SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
        Contents: '**'        
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        CleanTargetFolder: true
        OverWrite: true
    
     #Step 4, Publish artifacts
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        TargetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

I have a seperate release pipeline, which is attempting to deploy these files to an Azure Function App. However once this completes, the functions are missing. Using KUDU I can see the files have made their way up, however I think something is configured incorrectly.

This is what the artifact structure looks like when I browse for a 'Package or Folder', which to me seems incorrect.

Can anyone advise why my artifacts are not being produced in the format required for a function app?

[image]

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

From you screenshot about artifacts content, it seems that  you are directly packaging and publishing your project to Azure Function.

As far as I know, you should be missing the Build step.

You first need to add a build step according to your project type, and then deploy the built product to Azure function.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Deploy an Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-functions?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml)